# Indefinite Integration of real-variable function gives complex logarithm

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

Integrating real-variable function in Mathematica

```
 Integrate[1/Sqrt[2 x - x^2], x]
```

gives following output with complex logarithm
$$
\frac{2 \sqrt{x-2} \sqrt{x} \log \left(\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{x}\right)}{\sqrt{-(x-2) x}},
$$
while I expected $\arcsin (x-1)$ as a result of integration.

I tried to specify some assumptions like

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[2 x - x^2], x, Assumptions -> x > 0 && x < 2]
```

but this doesn't help.

Is it possible to avoid this complex logarithm and to tell Mathematica to integrate only over reals?

Comment: The imaginary part is constant over the interval `[0,2]` and equal to `I*Log[2]`. You can simply subtract it from the given formula. Remember that adding and subtracting constants from indefinite integrals is allowed.

Comment: With version 12 on my Mac, the integral evaluates to `-2*ArcSin[Sqrt[1 - x/2]]`

Comment: Version 12.0 on Windows 10 32 bit performs -2 ArcSin[Sqrt[1-x/2]]. The same in MathematicaOnline.

Comment: I have 11.2 version running on Linux. I get the same result using https://www.wolframalpha.com as well.

Comment: Antiderivatives need not return real-valued functions, even when the integrand is real when evaluated on the real line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Your result is

```
f1[x_] = 2 Sqrt[x - 2] Sqrt[x] Log[Sqrt[x - 2] + Sqrt[x]]/Sqrt[-(x - 2) x];
```

The version 12 result is

```
f2[x_] = Integrate[1/Sqrt[2 x - x^2], x]

(* -2 ArcSin[Sqrt[1 - x/2]] *)
```

`f2` is real when

```
fd = FunctionDomain[f2[x], x]

(* 0 <= x <= 2 *)
```

The difference between the results in the domain of interest is

```
Assuming[fd, 
 ReIm[f1[x] - f2[x]] // ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // 
  FullSimplify]

(* {0, Log[2]} *)
```

The real parts are equal and the imaginary parts differ by a constant. Consequently, as pointed out by @Roman, the indefinite integrals are equivalent.

More generally, for `x` real

```
ReIm[f1[x] - f2[x]] // ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // 
 FullSimplify[#, Element[x, Reals]] &
```

[image]

The difference is a piecewise constant. Again, showing that the indefinite integrals are equivalent.